# Quarkus Reactive Resteasy with Panache repository approach

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, resteasy, quarkus

I'm creating an application in Quarkus using Kotlin. Now I'm also creating a generic resource using Reactive Resteasy. Now the documentation of Quarkus is not using the repository approach when they use Panache Hibernate. My question is, is this still possible. Whenever I try it, it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting this error in my IDE:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
persist(T!) defined in io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepository
persist(T!, vararg T!) defined in io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepository
persist(Stream<T!>!) defined in io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepository
persist((Mutable)Iterable<T!>!) defined in io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepository

This is my code:

```
package com.fortuneapp.backend.application.rest

import com.fortuneapp.backend.application.domain.core.models.entities.Fruit
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.Panache
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepository
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepositoryBase
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni
import java.net.URI
import java.util.*
import javax.transaction.Transactional
import javax.validation.Valid
import javax.ws.rs.*
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
open class GenericResource<T>(
    private var repository: PanacheRepository<T>,
    ) {

    @GET
    fun getAll(): Uni<MutableList<T>> = repository.listAll()

    @POST
    @Transactional
    fun add(@Valid resource: T): Uni<Response> = Panache.withTransaction<T>(repository.persist(resource))
        .onItem().transform { id ->
            Response.created(
                URI.create(
                    "/fruits/$id"
                )
            ).build()
        }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun get(@PathParam("id") id: UUID): Uni<T> = repository.findById(id)

    @POST
    @Transactional
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun update(
        @PathParam("id")
        id: UUID,
        @Valid
        resource: T
    ): Uni<T>? = repository.persist(resource)

    @DELETE
    @Transactional
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun delete(@PathParam("id") id: UUID): Uni<Long>? = repository.deleteById(id)

}

private fun <Entity, Id> PanacheRepositoryBase<Entity, Id>.deleteById(id: UUID): Uni<Long>? =
    delete("id", id)

private fun <Entity, Id> PanacheRepositoryBase<Entity, Id>.findById(id: UUID): Uni<Entity> =
    find("id", id).firstResult()
```

With the @GET and other verbs, I'm able to use the repository approach, but not with the @POST. I haven't implemented the update method yet.

Small thanks to a user named geoand who has helped me with a previous question regarding this subject.

Below is the error I'm currently getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.5.21:compile (compile) on project fortuneapp-backend: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/ricardo/Documents/code/quarkus/fortuneapp-backend/src/main/kotlin/com/fortuneapp/backend/application/rest/GenericResource.kt:[26,77] Type mismatch: inferred type is Uni<T!>! but Supplier<Uni<TypeVariable(T)!>!>! was expected
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.5.21:compile (compile) on project fortuneapp-backend: Compilation failure
/Users/ricardo/Documents/code/quarkus/fortuneapp-backend/src/main/kotlin/com/fortuneapp/backend/application/rest/GenericResource.kt:[26,77] Type mismatch: inferred type is Uni<T!>! but Supplier<Uni<TypeVariable(T)!>!>! was expected

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/Users/ricardo/Documents/code/quarkus/fortuneapp-backend/src/main/kotlin/com/fortuneapp/backend/application/rest/GenericResource.kt:[26,77] Type mismatch: inferred type is Uni<T!>! but Supplier<Uni<TypeVariable(T)!>!>! was expected
```

Comment: Can you paste what error you are seeing?

Comment: Yes, I've added it in the description.

Comment: A larger part of the stacktrace would be useful

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly. I think the persist method is expecting something else, but I don't know what. I'm not really sure what this is: Supplier<Uni<TypeVariable(T)!>!>!

Comment: From the looks of it, I would say the return type of the method is a problem. Try setting it explicitly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How can I set the return type method explicitly?

Comment: In Kotlin I mean, try to use an explicit return type for the `update` method

Comment: I'm also not sure how to do that :\ Do you think adding an @ReactiveTransactional annotation would work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the resourse to the persist method. `repository.persist(resource)`.

Comment: Since you are using `Panache.withTransaction`, I guess you need not annotate the function as `@Transactional`. I had to do the same while working on reactive CRUD with Panache.

Comment: The @Transactional annotation configures the dispatching strategy to use a worker thread. you may refer [Quarkus-RestEasyReactive Blog](https://quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch/#combining-resteasy-reactive-hibernate-orm-and-kafka)

Comment: Hi @Haroon, thanks for your reply. When I pass the resource to the persist method, I'm getting the following message: Type mismatch.
Required:
Supplier<Uni<TypeVariable(T)!>!>!
Found:
Uni<T!>!

Comment: I removed the @Transactional annotation. This didn't help unfortunately.